# Replace symbolic matrix variables with values from struct array

Tags: matlab, matrix, symbolic-math

I have a matrix, `result`, that is extracted by a function. It contains

```
result =

    A1_1: [1x1 sym]
    A1_2: [1x1 sym]
    A2_1: [1x1 sym]
    A2_2: [1x1 sym]
    B1: [1x1 sym]
    B2: [1x1 sym]
```

where each element contains a value, e.g.:

```
result.A1_1=

ans =

200
```

I also have a symbolic matrix, `A`, that contains

```
[ A1_1, A1_2]
[ A2_1, A2_2]
```

I want to insert the values from `result` into the matrix `A` to obtain a valued matrix. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

It's not as well-known (and I don't know how old it is), but [`subs`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html) can directly take a [structure array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html), like your `result`, as an [input](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html#zmw57dd0e114586):

```
% Example data
result.A1_1 = sym(1);
result.A1_2 = sym(2);
result.A2_1 = sym(3);
result.A2_2 = sym(4);
result.B1 = sym(5);
result.B2 = sym(6);
A = sym('A',[2 2])

outA = subs(A,result)
```

which returns

```
outA =

[ 1, 2]
[ 3, 4]
```

If you also have `B = sym('B',[2 1])`, then you can do the following

```
outB = subs(B,result)
```

and get

```
outB =

 5
 6
```